# How do I run and automate making a database with PSQL

Tags: postgresql, shell, psql

I'm linking PSQL to a djangoREST api and I want it all to be automated, however I'm having trouble automating the creation of a database.  Currently in my code I have this

`initdb /usr/local/var/postgres`, and while this creates a database I don't know how to change the owner and db name like you would when you would normally run

`CREATE DATABASE <databasename>`

Comment: `initdb` does **not** "create a database" - it' creates a a database cluster (also referred to as an "instance"). A single database "cluster" can contain many database. `initdb` is usually only done once when installing Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question fully. Two actions(rename/change owenr), you could do following way.

- Rename database to new_databasename

`ALTER DATABASE <databasename> RENAME TO <new_databasename>;`

- Change database owner to new_user

`ALTER DATABASE <databasename> OWNER TO <new_databasename>;`